# Table Valued Parameter using pyodbc is Ignored

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

Trying to send data to a stored procedure that accepts Table Valued Parameter, neither it does any action nor returns any error.

```
    def InsertResults (self, dataset, name):

     try:
        sqlConn = self.sqlConnect()
        with sqlConn.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(f'CALL [dbo].[ImportAllocations] (?)', (dataset,))
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            print(result)
    except AssertionError as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        print(f"Inserted data into {name}. Records inserted {len(dataset)}")
```

My data is well formed in DataFrame.

[image]

This is stored procedure header:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[ImportAllocations](@DataTable [dbo].[udt_Allocation] READONLY)
```

Looking at SQL Profiler, and it seems to be ignoring the call. I tried some other simple example as per in following [issue](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/595), and that works fine.

Comment: So is `udt_Allocation` a stored procedure name or a user-defined data type? Because you're calling it like a stored procedure in your Python example.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, sorry error while simplifying the code. Calling the stored proc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with pandas Dataframe. This works once converted into tuples of single element without index.

```
listTuple = list(dataset.itertuples(index=False)) 
cursor.execute(f'EXEC {name} ?', (listTuple,))
```